# Keyboard problems in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, language

1. How can I change the language of the keyboard in Windows 7, because somehow I changed, but I don't know how?
2. Always when I wake up my computer from the sleep mode, the keyboard of the computer goes wrong. When I hit the <kbd>A</kbd> button it writes `as` and the opposite: when I hit the <kbd>S</kbd> button it writes `sa`? How can I make the keyboard work well?

Comment: Have you installed other keyboard layouts? Your keyboard problem likely is hardware problem and entirely seperate from installing a new keyboard layout in Windows 7 and should be an entirely seperate question.

Comment: try plugging in another keyboard to help troubleshoot. As for the language, look into how to add a 'language bar' .  that lets you switch languages easily and see which language you are using.

Comment: For the first question: [follow this guide](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/258824).